# I am trying to call a servlet from a jsp file to do the business logic and return to the same page

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, servlets

i have my project structure as follows

[image]

here is my jsp

```
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Binary Search</h2>

<form action ="SearchServlet" method = "post">
<label>Enter size of the list</label>
<input type="text" name ="listSize"><br><br>

<label>Here is your Generated list...!!!</label><br><br>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50"><c:out value="${list}"/> </textarea><br><br>

<label>Enter number to search in the list</label>
<input type="text" name ="searchNumber"><br><br>

<button type="submit" name="button" value="generate">Generate List</button>
<button type="submit" name="button" value="search">Search Number</button>
<button type="reset" name="button" value="reset">Reset</button>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

so when i click generate list button i am expecting it to redirect to my servlet and do my logic and return with arraylist to show it in text area.

here is my servlet

```
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public SearchServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    GenerateList newList = new GenerateList();
    SearchList searchList = new SearchList();
    String button = request.getParameter("button");

    ArrayList<Integer> newGeneratedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if ("generate".equals(button)) {
        newGeneratedList = newList.GeneratedList(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("listSize")));
        request.setAttribute("list",newGeneratedList);
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

    } else if ("search".equals(button)) {

    }
    //doGet(request, response);
}
```

}

but i get 404 not found error when click this.i have searched for hours and cannot find why,and i am still a beginner of servlet.any leads/help would be great.

here is my web.xml also

```
<web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
 <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
 <display-name>SearchServlet</display-name>
 <description></description>
 <servlet-class>SearchServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>BinarySearchServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/binarySearchServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: can you post the whole error you get?

Comment: @Damith This is the error message coming from server,The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Comment: Do you have any servlet mapping for `SearchServlet`? I can only see one for `BinarySearchServlet`.

Comment: Html form is not correct. Only one submit button is allowed

Comment: @DanielBarbarian yes i have updated that one as SearchServlet but no luck

Comment: On which url is it giving you the 404 error? The servlet url or the jsp url?

Comment: How did you create this project, and how are you launching it?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian when i click generate button its giving an error on servlet URL

Comment: @nitind this is a maven java web application created using maven simple web app archetype,and launching using tomcat 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use request dispatcher in place of sendRedirect in your servlet.

Try this:

```
 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher(jspName);
 rd.forward(request, response);
```

In parameter write your JSP name from where you have call this servlet. 
forward function will redirect to you at your desired page.

Comment: So it will redirect to the page i gave as the parameter? Also can you please check whether my project structure is correct?

Comment: Yes it will forward to that page and your structure seems to be ok.